# Call adapter.notifyItemChanged(position) but itemView at position+1 dismissed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I had a layout like this:

```
<recyclerView1>
    <itemView1>
        ...
        <recyclerView2>
            <itemView2/>
            <itemView2/>
            ...
        </>
    </>
    <itemView1 .../>
    <itemView1 .../>
    ...
</>
```

It's a `ReyclerView` nested another `RecyclerView`.

When recyclerView1.itemView(**pos**) in the screen, and recyclerView1.itemView(**pos+1**) out of the screen,

I tap recyclerView1.itemView(**pos**) to call recyclerView1.adapter.notifyItemChanged(**pos**),

all **itemView2** in recyclerView1.itemView(**pos+1**).recyclerView2 are dismissed.

Step:

1. itemView(pos) and itemView(pos+1)

[image]

2. scroll down to make itemView(pos+1) out of screen.

[image]

3. tap `itemView(pos)`  to call recyclerView1.adapter.notifyItemChanged(**pos**).
4. scroll up to show itemView(pos+1).

[image]

5. all **itemView2** in recyclerView1.itemView(**pos+1**).recyclerView2 are dismissed.

I don't know why.anyway to keep itemView2 in itemView(pos+1) showing?

hope for suggestion.:)

Comment: please share your adapter code

Comment: Post yout getView method code.